Check zip files integrity on disk
I need to check the downloaded zip files integrity.
I can use separately:
find . -name '*.zip'

and
less file.zip

But how can i combine these two:
find . -name '*.zip' | less

This does not list if the founded zip file is correct or not
Or is there any other solution?
Thank you for your help
Edit1:
By the two answers i combined them:
find . -name ".zip" -exec zip -T {} \; 

It's almost work properly, but when used together returns value like:
image.z01, and i need to press q to continue:
Could not find:
./image.z01
Hit c      (change path to where this split file is)
q      (abort archive - quit)
or ENTER  (try reading this split again): q

Title makes no sense based on the contents of the question. Please edit and correct the title.

Thank you so much Hannu a Zeye. I tried to combine the two answers:
find . -name "*.zip" -exec zip -T {} ;
This almost works great, except if there is an error :
Could not find:
xx.z0p // Why this returned if i searched for zip??
Hit c      (change path to where this split file is)
q      (abort archive - quit)
or ENTER  (try reading this split again):
zip error: Interrupted (aborting)
is it possible to just skip these ?
When i try to send the output to a file:
find . -name "*.zip" -exec zip -T {} ; > check_zip_files
Its stops by the first error

@Andrewboy you already know how to direct general output to a file (check_zip_files).  I've not used it however, there is a way to also direct input, in this case, probably the response q.

thank you @quill, the real issue is that the combination of these two commands return files like image.z01, i checked the folder and there is no such as file

What if @Andrewboy were to manually process each offending zip file by 1. unzipping it 2.giving the result a quick check then 3. recombining it into a replacement zip file?

You have a strange way of "checking integrity"...
sudo apt install zip
will install Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008). which has
$ zip --help
...
  -T   test zipfile integrity       ...

... the -T option meant to verify zip-files.
Then you might have a good way to find the files to process with find, ... and the find ... -exec option may be used to launch zip on those found files.

That might be the case with other zip implementations, but not the (OLD!) one you get by apt on a 24.04 install. The text above is cut and pasted from --help

If this question is How one might first seek files that match a pattern, in this case *.zip then perform a second command on each such file, in this case less.
This could be performed with just the find command using the -exec additional option of the find command.
find . -name "*.zip" -exec less {} \;

on each instance found, it will perform the string following the -exec option, in this case the less command.  {} means substitute the found name here.  The escaped semi-colon ends the string to be done.  In this instance, it's going to do a less command on each found .zip file.
